# How to test in sinon if the method is repeatedly called after timeout

Tags: javascript, timeout, mocha.js, sinon

I have a method start that calls itself after setTimeout. It checks if it has records then adjust the timeout if no records found. I want to test It in sinon if it's calling repeatedly.

Here's what the code is doing, this is a process that listens if a record is active or not. The `fetchAndMarkRecordAsActive` method fetches a record from DB then repeats the method itself, if no records are found it changes the timeout to a longer timeout about an hour. But if records are still fetching timeout remains default about 10 minutes.

```
ProcessReader.prototype.start = function () {
    const self = this;

    this.fetchAndMarkRecordAsActive(function (error) {
        if (error === 'NO_RECORD_FOUND') {
            self.timeout = self.longTimeout;
        }

        setTimeout(function () {
            self.start();
        }, self.timeout);
    });
}
```

How should I test this using sinon?

Here are the following test cases that I want to achieve:

- It should call itself after a timeout
- It should call repeatedly if records are found

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Change `this.longTimeout` to `self.longTimeout`. My mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');

describe('ProcessReader', () => {

  let startSpy;
  let fetchStub;
  let clock;

  beforeEach(() => {
    startSpy = sinon.spy(ProcessReader.prototype, 'start');
    fetchStub = sinon.stub(ProcessReader.prototype, 'fetchAndMarkRecordAsActive');
    clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    startSpy.restore();
    fetchStub.restore();
    clock.restore();
  });

  it('should work as expected', () => {
    const reader = new ProcessReader();

    fetchStub.yields();  // simulate records returned
    reader.start();
    sinon.assert.callCount(startSpy, 1);   // 1
    sinon.assert.callCount(fetchStub, 1);  // 1
    clock.tick(300000);  // wait half the timeout
    sinon.assert.callCount(startSpy, 1);   // still 1
    sinon.assert.callCount(fetchStub, 1);  // still 1
    clock.tick(300000);  // wait the other half
    sinon.assert.callCount(startSpy, 2);   // 2
    sinon.assert.callCount(fetchStub, 2);  // 2
    clock.tick(600000);  // wait the timeout
    sinon.assert.callCount(startSpy, 3);   // 3
    sinon.assert.callCount(fetchStub, 3);  // 3
    fetchStub.yields('NO_RECORD_FOUND');  // now simulate end of records
    clock.tick(600000);  // wait the timeout
    sinon.assert.callCount(startSpy, 4);   // 4
    sinon.assert.callCount(fetchStub, 4);  // 4
    clock.tick(600000);  // wait the timeout
    sinon.assert.callCount(startSpy, 4);   // still 4
    sinon.assert.callCount(fetchStub, 4);  // still 4
    clock.tick(3000000); // wait the rest of longTimeout
    sinon.assert.callCount(startSpy, 5);   // 5
    sinon.assert.callCount(fetchStub, 5);  // 5
    clock.tick(3600000); // wait longTimeout
    sinon.assert.callCount(startSpy, 6);   // 6
    sinon.assert.callCount(fetchStub, 6);  // 6
  });

});
```

---

Note that you should also use `self` to access `longTimeout`.

---

For reference here is the code I used to create the above test:

```
const ProcessReader = function () {
  this.longTimeout = 3600000;
  this.timeout = 600000;
}

ProcessReader.prototype.fetchAndMarkRecordAsActive = function () { }

ProcessReader.prototype.start = function () {
  const self = this;

  this.fetchAndMarkRecordAsActive(function (error) {
    if (error === 'NO_RECORD_FOUND') {
      self.timeout = self.longTimeout;  // <= use self.longTimeout
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
      self.start();
    }, self.timeout);
  });
}
```

Comment: @per.eight glad to help :)